# Two Similar Measures on a Probability Space

Tags: measure-theory, martingales, singularity

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $Q$ be
>   another probability measure on $\mathscr{F}$, and let
>   $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ be a non-decreasing sequence
>   of $\sigma$-fields in $\mathscr{F}$, for random variables
>   $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ on  $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$.
>
> Suppose that the distribution of the random vector
>   $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ has densities $p_n(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ and
>   $q_n(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, with respect to $n$-dimensional Lebesgue
>   measure, under the measures $P$ and $Q$ respectively.
>
> Now, suppose the $Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed
>   under both $P$ and $Q$.

(So, for example, $p_n(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=p(y_1)\cdots p(y_n)$ for density $p$ on the line).

If $P[Y_n \in H]\neq Q[Y_n\in H]$ for some $H \in \mathscr{R}^1$ and $Z_n=I_{[Y_n\in H]}$, then what happens to $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k$ by the strong law of large numbers?

I mean, does it converge to $P[Y_1 \in H]$ or to $Q[Y_1 \in H]$?

Additionally, if $P$ dominates $Q$ when both are restricted to $\mathscr{F}_n$, can $P$ and $Q$ be mutually singular on $\mathscr{F}$ and how?

Thanks and Regards!

Comment: $S_n \to E_P Y_k$ ae. [$P$]. and $S_n \to E_Q Y_k$ ae. [$Q$]. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat, why should $P$ and $Q$ have disjoint support?

Comment: Indeed, this means there is an event $A$ such that $P(A)=1$ and $Q(A)=0$. One then says that $P$ and $Q$ are singular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure (The name is slightly misleading, if you ask me, since one means that each measure is singular *with respect to the other measure*, but such is the usage.)

Comment: In the setting of your question, $A$ can be made explicit, for example,  $$A=\left\{\omega\in\Omega\;:\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nZ_k(\omega)=P(Y_1\in H)\right\}.$$

Comment: According to my post, $P[Y_n \in H] \neq Q[Y_n \in H]$ for some $H$, and there is no need for P and Q to have _disjoint_ support, (i.e. be **mutually singular**).  I don't know how to derive the mutual singularity on $\mathscr{F}$.